# <ons-carousel>のメソッドについて教えて下さい。

Tags: javascript, jquery, onsen-ui, angularjs, cordova

[ons-carouselのメソッド](http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-carousel.html#methods-summary)を幾つか試しています。
ons-carouselから以下の情報が取得できるのでしょうか

1. ons-carousel-item要素数
2. 自ons-carousel-itemが最終かどうか(true,false)

もし上記情報の取得情報がご存知でしたら、ご教示のほどお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

要素数については以下で取得できるようです。
`_getCarouselItemCount()`

ただしこのメソッドは、見て分かる通りOnsenUIの内部用のメソッドであるため、今後のバージョンアップ等で名前の変更や、削除されることもあるのを覚悟しておく必要が有ります。

後は、現在のindex番号（０から始まる数値）は取得できるので、上のメソッドで取得した要素数と比較して最終のアイテムであるかどうかは判断できると思います。

Comment: ご回答いただき、誠にありがとうございます。
「_getCarouselItemCount()」は試しに使ってみます。
非公認メソッドのようなので、今後のことを考慮して
対応しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

`ons-carousel-item`の要素数を取得するだけなら
`document.getElementsByTagName('ons-carousel-item').length`
とかでも良い気がします。

Comment: ご回答いただき、誠にありがとうございます。
ons-carouselタグが単一ならこれでもいいかと思いますが、
複数の場合は「_getCarouselItemCount()」のようですね。
試してみます。